# skipping controller and action names mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm developing a project using ASP.NET MVC

> im using ASP.NET Web Application with MVC enabled

I Have a Home controller which contains default Index action, there is a list of stuff that I can access like this

> site.com/?parameter=test1

but i want to be able to access the list like this

> site.com/test1

where test1 is the parameter and used as a search parameter.

i have tried the below examples, but none of them worked

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and this

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the [Route] attribute above an action and leave the defaults in your startup.

```
[Route("/{id?}"]
public IActionResult Index(string id)
{
  return View();
}
```

for net framework use below

```
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
    routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

Comment: im using "ASP.NET Web Application with MVC enabled" i get this error when i try your suggestion **"The type or namespace name 'IActionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**